# Cannot create a macro for multicolumn in LyX

Tags: macros, lyx, multicolumn

I am trying to write a block diagonal matrix in LyX which clearly shows the blocks by separating them using vertical and horizontal lines. I found that I can use `\cline{i-j}` to draw a horizontal line between columns i and j. Similarly, I found that I can use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}` to write an element in the matrix which has a vertical line to its right.

I tried to create a math macro for the `\multiline` command because the first two arguments are always the same in my matrix. I did it as follows,

[image]

However, when I close the file and reopen it, the macro changes to this

[image]

I do not understand why this happens. I have used macros before and they never changed like this. Is there any problem in defining a macro for `\multicolumn`?

Comment: Since this is a TeX-LaTeX site, I'd rather report such (obvious) bugs at https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome or LyX user/developer newsgroups.

Comment: This is going to be fixed in the upcoming LyX 2.3 and 2.2.3 (see http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10466). For now you can replace `\multicolumn` with `\csname multicolumn\endcsname` and it will be preserved on loading. As said, this is not really a question for tex.se.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in LyX that has been reported at the appropriate place (http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10466) and will be fixed in an upcoming version.